# How to reload RenderBody only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have Layout with navigation menu, when I click menu - whole page reloaded.So I tried page reload using ajax link but i have still problem. My problem is can't see javascript code of view and don't change url link.How to reload just partial Views in RenderBody() section?

In LayOut

```
 <a href="@Url.Action(Model.SubMenuVMs[0].ActionName,  Model.SubMenuVMs[0].ProgramName )" class="ajaxLink">
@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SubMenuVMs[0].MenuDescription)
</a>

 <div id="MainContent">
     @RenderBody()
 </div>

<script>
 $(function () { 
        $("a.ajaxLink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#MainContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case you need to use `angular` or `react` to do that easily. You can do it with `jQuery` as well. In that case you need to do that by replacing `html` in your content area. Here is your rendering section

```
<div id="MainContent">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Take an extra `div` there where you want to switch viewes.

```
<div id="MainContent">
    @RenderBody()
    <div id="contentView"></div>
</div>
```

Now what you need to is, create `ajax` request to your controller and return partial views and replace that view in that particular area in `contentView`. Here is an action for a partial view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PartialViewUser(){
    return Partial("_UserPartial");
}
```

Create an ajax request to that `action`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Controller/PartialViewUser',
    success: function(resp){
        // Clear html from contentView ID
        // Then append new response
        $("#contentView").empty().append(resp);
    },
    error: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

You are good to go. This will switch viewes for you inside `contentView` div. Remember, you need only return partial view to achieve that.

Comment: Thank for your reply. But your code doesn't change url link.  My desire want to change url link and see javascript code at partial view.

Comment: Nop! It won't update url. You can integrate angular to your project in order to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try Pjax library, Check this  https://github.com/MoOx/pjax

In Javascript

```
var pjax = new Pjax({
    elements: "a", 
    selectors: [
        "#MainContent",
    ],
})
```

.NET

```
public ActionResult Product(int id)
{
      var product = productRepository.GetById(id);
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["X-PJAX"]))
          return View(product);
      else
          return PartialView("/Views/Home/Product.cshtml", product);
}
```